# The type or namespace name 'IPublishedContent' could not be found in Umbraco 8

Tags: umbraco8

I've media picker in Umbraco 8 and I want to display image in my cshtml page.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<body>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="page-header-box">
            <img src="images/Leadership.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="ld-content-box gradientbackground">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <h3 class="ip-title">Leadership</h3>
                <ul class="aboutus-leadership-listing">
                    @foreach (var childPage in Model.Children())
                    {
                        <li data-aos="fade-up">
                            <div class="abll-image-box">
                                @{
                                    var leaderImage = childPage.Value<IPublishedContent>("leaderImage");
                                }
```

[image]

But I am getting error :

> The type or namespace name 'IPublishedContent' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't it is issue because of Umbraco V8 or is there anything missing?

**UPDATED:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`IPublishedContent` is defined in the `Umbraco.Core.Models` namespace.

You should have an entry

```
<add namespace="Umbraco.Core.Models" />
```

in the `system.web.webPages.razor/pages/namespaces` section of `Views\Web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

IPublishedContent moved again, now it resides in Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent:

```
using Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

For namespace and Library

```
@using Umbraco.Core.Models
```

For Model

```
@model Umbraco.Core.Models
```

For Iterate the list on Razor Page (You Have to use foreach loop for access the list items)